# List comprehension to append to new list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to iterate through each element in list "food", and if that element is in list "menu", I want to append that element to a new list "order". I have been able to do this with the for loop below:

```
food = ['apple', 'donut', 'carrot', 'chicken']
menu = ['chicken pot pie', 'warm apple pie', 'Mac n cheese']
order = []

for i in food:
    for x in menu:
        if i in x:
            order.append(x)

# Which gives me

order = ['warm apple pie', 'chicken pot pie']
```

I know this works, and this is what I want, but I am trying to improve my code to make it more pythonic. I have tried this:

```
order = [x for x in menu for y in food]
```

But that gives me:

```
order = ['chicken pot pie', 'chicken pot pie', 'chicken pot pie', 'chicken pot pie',
         'warm apple pie', 'warm apple pie', 'warm apple pie', 'warm apple pie', 
         'Mac n cheese', 'Mac n cheese', 'Mac n cheese','Mac n cheese']
```

I can see that it is appending matches for each element in food, but I'm not sure how to do list comprehension to get my desired output.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this I get the same output

```py
order = [x for i in food for x in menu if i in x]
```

**Output:**
`['warm apple pie', 'chicken pot pie']`

Also you could check [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/list_comprehension.html) for mor examples.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
order = [x for x in menu for y in food if( y in x)]
```

Comment: `if( y in x)` can be replaced with `if y in x`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the help of `set`, therefore you need only one for loop

```
order = [item for item in menu if len(set(item.split()) & set(food)) > 0]
```

Comment: So I was thinking about this, but I need to preserve the order they are in as well, so I didn't use one. Can you think of a way to keep order in a set?

Comment: @Yankswin1 I don't understand, do you want to preserve the word order of a dish? As long as you are comparing with a list of single words, looks like the word order doesn't matter.

Comment: Lol, I am working with private health information so I'm using dummy code in my question. So the data I am using doesn't have single words, I'm more just trying to get an idea for the syntax of the list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

```
order = list(filter((None).__ne__, [x if y in x else None for x in menu for y in food]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
order = [menu_item for menu_item in menu for food_item in food if food_item in menu_item]
```

I tried and got correct output as below:

```
>>> order = [menu_item for menu_item in menu for food_item in food if food_item in menu_item]
>>> order
['chicken pot pie', 'warm apple pie']
```